# How to identify rect of list item in an auto-arranged list?

Tags: delphi, custom-controls, listitem

I'm building a custom list control, similar to a list view but lighter. It has properties `ItemWidth` and `ItemHeight` for each of its items, and the items are in a `TOwnedCollection`. Each item is the same size. I also have properties for `Margins` and `ItemSpacing` to specify how far apart to position each item.

The problem is when it comes to calculating each item's position to best fit them in the current control space. The control has only vertical scrolling, and no horizontal. Therefore, I need to recognize when an item cannot fit in the list and bring it to the next line.

To make this even trickier, I have to also be able to identify if a given point is within an item's rect area, for handling mouse events. So to solve this, I decided to put a function on each item `GetRect` which will return that item's `Rect` area on the control. But how do I make this function calculate this?

The two main implementations of this function will be in the `Paint` of the control:

```
for X := 0 to FItems.Count - 1 do begin
  Canvas.Rectangle(FItems[X].GetRect);
end;
```

And when identifying if a point is in this item's area:

```
for X := 0 to FItems.Count - 1 do begin
  R:= FItems[X].GetRect;
  Result := (P.X > R.Left) and (P.X < R.Right) and (P.Y > R.Top) and (P.Y < R.Bottom);
end;
```

Comment: It will probably help you understand things if you stop thinking about it as a list-view control and start thinking about it as a grid control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Knowing the position of any cell of a grid does not require calculating all previous cells' locations. That's the great thing about a grid. Each cell has a predictable location.

To start, you need to know how many cells can be arranged horizontally in a single row. Using the values from [the first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10875117/33732), that's given by this equation:

```
CellsPerRow := (CW - ML - MR + SH) div (IW + SH);
```

That takes the total client width, subtracts the margins, and divides by the effective width of a single cell, given by adding the item width with the inter-item spacing. One cell of each row doesn't have spacing (because it abuts an edge of the control), so we pretend that the client area is actually wider by `SH` pixels.

Now that we know how many items fit in a row, we can calculate which (zero-based) row any item belongs in:

```
ItemRow := Item.Index div CellsPerRow;
```

The (zero-based) position within that row (the column) is also easy to calculate:

```
ItemColumn := Item.Index mod CellsPerRow;
```

Now we can calculate the position of the cell:

```
LP := ML + ItemColumn * (IW + SH);
TP := MT + ItemRow * (IH + SV);
```

Bringing it all together, we get this:

```
function TMyListItemGrid.GetCellsPerRow: Integer;
begin
  Result := (ClientWidth - Margins.Left - Margins.Right + SpacingHorz) div (ItemWidth + SpacingHorz);
end;

function TMyListItem.GetRect: TRect;
var
  Row, Col: Integer;
  EffectiveWidth, EffectiveHeight: Integer;
begin
  EffectiveWidth := Owner.ItemWidth + Owner.SpacingHorz;
  EffectiveHeight := Owner.ItemHeight + Owner.SpacingVert;

  Row := Index div Owner.CellsPerRow;
  Result.Top := Owner.Margins.Top + Row * EffectiveHeight;
  Result.Bottom := Result.Top + Owner.ItemHeight;

  Col := Index mod Owner.CellsPerRow;
  Result.Left := Owner.Margins.Left + Col * EffectiveWidth;
  Result.Right := Result.Left + Owner.ItemWidth;
end;
```

Be careful about letting the control get too narrow, or letting the margins get too wide. If that happens, then the `CellsPerRow` property could become zero, and that will cause exceptions from all the `GetRect` calls. Things will probably also look strange if `CellsPerRow` becomes negative. You'll want to enforce a certain minimum width for your control.

Answer (score -1):

I've broken this procedure down to demonstrate how to calculate such positions:

```
function TMyListItem.GetRect: TRect;
var
  I: Integer;   //Iterator
  LP: Integer;  //Left position
  TP: Integer;  //Top position
  CW: Integer;  //Client width
  CH: Integer;  //Client height
  IW: Integer;  //Item width
  IH: Integer;  //Item height
  SV: Integer;  //Vertical spacing
  SH: Integer;  //Horizontal spacing
  ML: Integer;  //Margin left
  MT: Integer;  //Margin top
  MR: Integer;  //Margin right
  MB: Integer;  //Margin bottom
  R: TRect;     //Temp rect
begin //'Owner' = function which returns the control
  //Initialize some temporary variables...
  CW:= Owner.ClientWidth;
  CH:= Owner.ClientHeight;
  IW:= Owner.ItemWidth;
  IH:= Owner.ItemHeight;
  SV:= Owner.SpacingVert;
  SH:= Owner.SpacingHorz;
  ML:= Owner.Margins.Left;
  MT:= Owner.Margins.Top;
  MR:= Owner.Margins.Right;
  MB:= Owner.Margins.Bottom;
  LP:= ML;  //Default left position to left margin
  TP:= MT;  //Default top position to top margin
  for I := 0 to Collection.Count - 1 do begin
    R:= Rect(LP, TP, LP + IW, TP + IH);
    if Self.Index = I then begin
      Result:= R;
      Break;
    end else begin
      //Calculate next position
      LP:= LP + IW + SV;    //move left position by item width + vertical spacing
      if (LP + IW + MR) >= CW then begin //Does item fit?
        LP:= ML;            //reset left position
        TP:= TP + IH + SH;  //drop down top position to next line
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Here is a sample of what it produced:

[image]

There should be a better performing alternative. This procedure is doing a loop of calculations, so a list of hundreds of items may show slower results.

Comment: You have `SV` and `SH` mixed up, no? It makes no sense to add vertical spacing to an item's horizontal position.

Comment: @RobKennedy Depends on how you look at it - I was imagining a vertical line which spaces each item from each other.

Comment: A vertical line that travels through the horizontal spacing. The spacing is affecting the item's horizontal position. It might be spacing where a vertical line goes, but that doesn't affect vertical space in any way.